# Data manipulatipons with lists of the list

Tags: python, pandas, nested-lists, evaluation

I have asked this questions several times, but in the wrong way, so I have decided to ask from very beginning:

I did clustering. And I have found 2 clusters.

```
clusters = [[cluster 1 data],[cluster 2 data]]
```

clusters =

```
    [[      ordinal  id_easy  latitude  longitude
      1226        1      141   11.1024     7.7498
      1229        4      141   11.1076     7.7563,
            ordinal  id_easy  latitude  longitude
      3792        1    22087   11.1134     7.7145,
            ordinal  id_easy  latitude  longitude
      4249        1    22079   11.0016     7.5629
      4250        2    22079   11.0026     7.5632],
     [      ordinal  id_easy  latitude  longitude
      3669        1    19421   11.0760     7.6786
      3696       28    19421   11.0287     7.6679,
            ordinal  id_easy  latitude  longitude
      4172        1    19330   11.0430     7.6699
      4191       20    19330   11.0020     7.6530,
            ordinal  id_easy  latitude  longitude
      1580        1    23140   11.0635     7.5231
      1583        4    23140   11.0646     7.5194]]
```

Having done with that I need to evaluate my model. But to do that I want to prepare my data for that (and this is a question). I have centers of each cluster (computed with sklearn). I want to compare every **center** to every couple of **longitude and latitude**. By working only(!) with shown columns.

To do this I need to prepare data in the following way:

[image: desired table]

Having done this how to call data related to Cluster 0

I need to be able to call cluster and it will give me a dataframe(?) with 2 columns. Because then I will compare values of every cluster with its center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try look at `concat`

```
 l= [pd.concat(x) for x in clusters ]
 pd.concat(l,keys=range(len(l)))
```

Comment: Almost perfect! One question: How to call data related to cluster 0?

Comment: @Mamed using df.loc[0]